# Need JQuery to mark checkboxes checked from list/array from database

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Using SQL 2008 Server and the latest JQuery. If I query a column from the database and get the list/array how do I mark the checkboxes in each checkbox group 'checked'? Example checkbox groups and lists below:

list for category '1,7,20' (Jquery should mark checkboxes with values 1,7,10 checked)
list for likes '2,3' (Jquery should mark checkboxes with values 2 and 3 checked)

```
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" class="category" name="category" value="14" />Blah
    <input type="checkbox" class="category" name="category" value="1" />Blah1
    <input type="checkbox" class="category" name="category" value="7" />Blah2
    <input type="checkbox" class="category" name="category" value="20" />Blah3
    <input type="checkbox" class="likes" name="likes" value="17" />Apple
    <input type="checkbox" class="likes" name="likes" value="3" />Apple1
    <input type="checkbox" class="likes" name="likes" value="2" />Apple2
    <input type="checkbox" class="likes" name="likes" value="13" />Apple3
</form>
```

I tried the following JQuery code, but it doesn't work:

```
$.each(['1,7,20'], function (index, item) {
    if ($('.category').val() === item) {
        $(".category").prop("checked", true);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing an array with a single element that is the string `1,7,20`, not an array with three elements that are the strings `1`,`7` and `20`, so I'm not sure why you're expecting it to work. If your input is in fact the string, you can split it on the comma to get an array with your numbers as strings:

```
var myString = '1,7,20';
var myArray = myString.split(',');
```

Then pass `myArray` to the `$.each()` function call.

There's also a problem with the code inside the function you've passed to `$.each()`. If you do call `.val()` on a jQuery object containing multiple elements, it will usually return the value for the **first** element only. You'll need to iterate again over the collection of elements, and use `this` to refer to the current element.

```
$.each(myArray, function(index, item){
    $('.category').each(function(){
        if(this.value === item) {
            this.checked = true;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Something must be wrong with my Jquery code, even when I pass the string as an array, no checkboxes are checked. What am I missing?

Comment: @user1252552 I didn't really look at the rest of the code after noticing the initial mistake I commented on, but have done so now. Edited my answer to include the explanation for the other problem with the code.

Comment: We're getting there. The newer Jquery code is marking all the checkboxes checked now. Can I target the checkboxes by class and by value or is that not needed? Something like $(".category.value(item)").prop("checked", true);

Comment: @user1252552 I'm an idiot who can't modify code correctly! You want to be using `$(this)` rather than `$('.category')` inside the `if` statement. Will edit the answer.

Comment: Awesome, it works now. Thanks very much. (No, I'm the idiot, I had $(this) in my original code, but couldn't get the code to work so I went with .category to test and never put it back. )

Answer (score 0):

By the way, semantically, you should be using a [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/). You can do the same thing while simultaneously increasing the readability of your code.